# Is it possible to separate the different level contours given by imcontour in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I am using the image processing toolbox and the

```
 imcontour
```

function. I have 2 questions.

1) what are the levels exactly ? 
2) How can I separate the different level contours given in c when using

```
  [c,h]=imcontour(Img,3)
```

When displaying the contour, Matlab presents different colors for the different levels. I would like to retrieve the coordinates of the inner contour only, how can I do this ? On this image, I presented the output of the imcontour function with level 1, level 2, level 3 and level 4. I am only interested in the yellow part of the level 3 image.

[image: output of imcontour function for different levels]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible, but not really trivial. The `C` matrix returned by `[C,h]=imcontour(Img,3)` is the [ContourMatrix](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.contour-properties.html#budgut_-ContourMatrix). This is a 2xN array containing all vertices for the lines drawn.

Say you have 3 contours (as per your second input argument to `imcountour`), and want to find the vertices to the 3rd contour (which is what I presume is the yellow line). You need to skip ahead two contours first:

```
index = 1;
for ii=1:2             % skip 2 contours
   index = index + 1 + C(2,index);
end
N = C(2,index);        % number of vertices for 3rd contour
level = C(1,index);    % grey-level of 3rd contour
vertices = C(:,index+(1:N));
```